# Set Angular component input based on stylesheet

Tags: css, angular, sass

I am using a component (from an external lib) that has a custom size input which sets the size of the element and applies some additional styling:

```
<some-element size="small">
```

In my scss file I use `media` to apply some styling based on browser width, so I was wandering if there was some way to also set the `size` input based on this size.

I know I can put two elements with different input in my template lige this

```
<some-element class="small" size="small">
<some-element class="large" size="large">
```

and then toggle them using `display` for the `small` and `large` classes.

However, I would like to avoid this since `some-element` has quite a few inputs and outputs, which would lead to a lot of code duplication since I am using multiple instances of `some-element`.

Can this be done somehow? Perhaps by setting a size variable in my scss and then reading it in my component? Although I am not sure how to do this while supporting dynamic browser resizing.

Comment: You could define the same breakpoints you're using in your media queries in the code, and then use `BreakpointObserver` from the CDK to observe those changes. See the docs [here](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview).

Comment: @TotallyNewb Brilliant! It works. Post an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: It would be too low quality for a full answer, and I'm currently too lazy to elaborate on the topic. Just glad I could help :)